# Можно ли так отнимать так индексы?

Tags: pascal

На вход программы поступает последовательность из N целых положительных чисел. Рассматриваются все пары различных элементов последовательности (элементы пары не обязаны стоять в последовательности рядом, порядок элементов в паре неважен). Необходимо определить количество произвольных пар, произведение чисел и разность индексов которых кратна 3.
Описание входных и выходных данных
В первой строке входных данных задаётся количество чисел N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10000). В каждой из последующих N строк записано одно натуральное число, не превышающее 10000. В качестве результата программа должна вывести одно число: количество найденных пар.
Пример входных данных №1:
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Выходные данных для приведенного выше примера:
3

```
var
a: array[1..10000] of integer;
N, i, j, x, b: integer;

begin
x := 0;
readln(N);
for i := 1 to N do
readln(a[i]);
for i := 1 to N - 1 do
for j := i + 1 to N do
  if ((a[i] * a[j]) mod 3 = 0) and ((i - j) mod 3 = 0) then
    x := x + 1;
writeln(x);
end.
```

Можно ли так отнимать индексы?  `((i - j) mod 3 = 0)`  Это рабочий способ? Или есть какой-то более универсальный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это рабочий способ.

Более оптимально же будет не проверять все разности индексов, а пройти только по нужным индексам с шагом 3

```
for i := 1 to N - 1 do
j := i + 3;
while i <= N do begin
   if ((a[i] * a[j]) mod 3 = 0) then
     x := x + 1;
   inc(j, 3);
end;
```